# Watson STT Java - MediaType AUDIO_WEBM can not be resolved

Tags: java, api, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

The MediaType AUDIO_WEBM can not be resolved. Am I missing something? I receive the error below.

```
[ERROR] /C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/workspace/ListenApp/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/speech_to_text/v1/util/MediaTypeUtils.java:[39,43] cannot find symbol

[ERROR] symbol:   variable AUDIO_WEBM
```

My dependencies are;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>speech-to-text</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp-ws -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp-ws</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependencies are wrong. You are trying to use `3.0.0-RC1` and `3.7.2` at the same time. You also don't need to include `okhttp` it comes with the SDK already.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>speech-to-text</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use other services you could include them one by one or you could include all the services using:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/index.html) suggests WEBM is available as from April 10, 2017:

> The Text to Speech service was updated on April 10, 2017. The service now supports the audio/webm audio format and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). For information about all recent changes to the service, see the Release notes.

I have done some investigation ...

- This [commit](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/commit/1c93196158ba0fbf955216d8dc98aa0b552ccb21) shows the introduction of the WEBM format on April 10, 2017.
- However, the tag release [java-sdk-3.7.2](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/releases/tag/java-sdk-3.7.2) was on the 7th April 2017 .

It seems that you will need to either wait for the next release or use an unreleased version of STT to get WEBM support.